# Python get request hangs for long duration api calls even though the api server side response is completed

Tags: python, linux, api, server

I have looked at every related article or answer but could not get this resolved.I have a python script which calls a set of apis sequentially and write data to a file. Some apis take time to return response in ~30-40 mins and some return results in milliseconds.

When I run this python script on my local mac machine, it runs smooth and as intended.
When I run the same script on a remote Linux server, the python scripts initiates the call to the apis, it starts the first api, completes successfully and then starts the second api but never completes after that and just hangs forever.

The apis are completely accessible from the linux server, so there is no access issue.

I juggled the sequence of api calls to check if there's a problem with certain api but all the apis are working. It's just that if the python script executes for too long it just hangs.

Here's my python file test.py

```
import requests
import json, collections
import time

sourceDataApiBaseUrl = "https://apiserver.com/"
dataSinkBaseUrl = "/outputFolder"
jobs = [
    {"jobTitle":"API1","dataSourceApi":"api1/", "dataSinkFile": "1.csv"},
    {"jobTitle":"API2","dataSourceApi":"api2/", "dataSinkFile": "2.csv"},
    {"jobTitle":"API3","dataSourceApi":"api3/", "dataSinkFile": "3.csv"},
    {"jobTitle":"API4","dataSourceApi":"api4/", "dataSinkFile": "4.csv"},
    {"jobTitle":"API5","dataSourceApi":"api5/", "dataSinkFile": "5.csv"}
  ]

for job in jobs:
    print '\n'+job['jobTitle']+' job started..'

    # fetch data from the api
    print '   '+job['dataSourceApi']+' api started ...'
    step1Seconds = time.time()
    response = requests.get(sourceDataApiBaseUrl+job['dataSourceApi'])
    jsonResponse = json.loads(response.text, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
    print '   '+job['dataSourceApi']+' api completed, time taken in seconds='+str(time.time() - step1Seconds)

    csvContent = ""
    for myrow in jsonResponse:
        csvContent += '"'+'","'.join(myrow.values())+'"\n'
    csvContent = csvContent.rstrip("\n")

    print '   '+'file writing started ...'
    step2Seconds = time.time()
    f= open(dataSinkBaseUrl+"/"+job['dataSinkFile'],"w+")
    f.write(csvContent)
    f.close()
    print '   '+'file writing completed, records='+str(len(jsonResponse))+', time taken in seconds='+str(time.time() - step2Seconds)
```

**P.S**
I also tried adding timeout to the python requests.get method.I tried putting a longer timeout say 3600 seconds while the actual time for api completion is around 2400 seconds. In this case python throws a read timeout after 1h (3600s). I checked the api calling logs on the api server and it finishes in around 2400 seconds but the client never got the response and times out :(

Comment: Have you checked the memory? `import sys; sys.getsizeof(object)` Debug print and check the size of the objects you're getting from the apis using this.

Comment: @ycx the size of the object is around 12mb which I think should not be an issue.